# Add active scroll page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I would like to know how I can add an asset when the scroll down menu for each div

```
    $(".link").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/r8325qy8/

Comment: What do you mean by adding an asset?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r8325qy8/1/ for example: http://screencast.com/t/5mO8UxWO

Comment: You want to mark the current clicked element? so when clicking on Branding it will turn yellow and Nosotros will turn white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by removing the `.current` class from any other element and add that class to the target which was clicked.

```
$(".link").click(function () {

            var target = $(this); // select the current clicked element

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
            }, 500, function() {
                $('li.current').removeClass('current'); // remove all previous marking
                target.parent().addClass('current'); // apply the css class to the clicked element
            });
            return false;
        });
```

[A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8325qy8/2/)